# pyautogui screenshot command is not working

Tags: python, screenshot, pyautogui

```
import pyautogui

myScreenshot = pyautogui.screenshot()
myScreenshot.save(r'C:\Users\"my user name"\PycharmProjects\"my project"\   name.png')
```

[image]

I don't know what I did wrong but any similar command is not working (I have installed `pyautogui`).

Answer (score 1):

If you already have `PIL` *(Pillow)* installed, you'll need to upgrade it via the command prompt command

```
pip install Pillow --upgrade
```

Comment: I installed pillow and and the upgrade but i still have the same error

Comment: @ΙωακείμΠαπαϊωάννου If you have multiple python editors, make sure that you installed PIL into the editor that you are running the code in.

Comment: I installed it from the pycharm terminal so probably that isnt the problem

Answer (score 0):

Just install Pillow package using pip:

```
pip install Pillow
```

or

```
pip3 install Pillow
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to upgrade your PyAutoGui module using the following command:

```
pip install pyautogui --upgrade
```

I hope it helps you!